# ¿Como poner la fecha y hora actual en español con SimpleDateFormat?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

tengo un problema a la hora de configurar la fecha en español en Kotlin con SimpleDateFormat.

Al introducir

```
val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale("es", "ES"))
val currentdate = sdf.format(Date())
val fechaactual = sdf.parse(currentdate)
Log.d("fechaactual", fechaactual.toString())
```

Recibo el output:

```
D/fechaactual: Sat Jul 24 11:28:57 EDT 2021
```

Cuando en España son las 17:30. Me gustaria recibir la hora correcta de España, es decir, que no este en EDT, sino en UTC+1 o en la hora de Madrid.

¿Saben en que me estoy equivocando? Gracias de antemano

Comment: Dónde defines `fechaactual`? Y cuál es el resultado esperado?

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem disculpa, me he equivocado al escribir las lineas. Ya esta arreglado, un saludo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ver si con éste formato te funciona

```
SimpleDateFormat fechaEspanol = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy - HH:mm:ss", Locale.forLanguageTag("es_ES"));
System.out.println(fechaEspanol.format(new Date()));
```

Si no, podrías utilizar:

```
DateTimeFormatter fecha0 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss: " + fecha0.format(LocalDateTime.now()));
```

dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss-> 26/05/21 22:45:21

```
DateTimeFormatter fecha1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MMM/yy HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println("dd/MMM/yyy HH:mm:ss: " + fecha1.format(LocalDateTime.now()));
```

dd/MMM/yyy HH:mm:ss-> 26/may/21 22:45:21

```
DateTimeFormatter fecha2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MMMM/yy HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println("dd/MMMM/yy HH:mm:ss: " + fecha2.format(LocalDateTime.now()));
```

dd/MMMM/yy HH:mm:ss-> 26/mayo/21 22:45:22

```
DateTimeFormatter fecha3 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss: " + fecha3.format(LocalDateTime.now()));
```

dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss-> 26/05/2021 22:45:22

```
DateTimeFormatter fecha4 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm");
System.out.println("dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm: " + fecha4.format(LocalDateTime.now()));
```

dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm-> 26/may/2021 22:45

```
DateTimeFormatter fecha5 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MMMM/yyyy hh:mm");
System.out.println("dd/MMMM/yyyy hh:mm:ss: " + fecha5.format(LocalDateTime.now()));
```

dd/MMMM/yyyy hh:mm:ss-> 26/mayo/2021 10:45

```
DateTimeFormatter fecha6 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE dd/MMMM/yyyy hh:mm");
System.out.println("EEEE, dd/MMMM/yyyy hh:mm:ss: " + fecha6.format(LocalDateTime.now()));
```

EEEE, dd/MMMM/yyyy hh:mm:ss: miércoles 26/mayo/2021 11:01

El problema de tu código se puede deber a la configuración local de tu equipo

Comment: Efectivamente, el emulador tenia la hora mal configurada, gracias

Answer (score 4):

El `Locale` solamente afecta el formato (sintaxis) pero no va a cambiar la hora. Es decir que independientemente del format y locale que le indiques, la fecha y hora siempre va a ser la que tenga configurada el dispositivo. Para cambiarla tendrías que especifar una `TimeZone` diferente

```
val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale("es", "ES"))
sdf.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC+1")
val currentdate = sdf.format(Date())
Log.d("fechaactual", currentdate)
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, el error era un fallo tonto. El emulador tenia la hora mal configurada